# SQL query on array or hash table

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

Does anyone have an inventive way of treating a multidimensional array or hash table like a database table in such a way that you can perform simple SELECT-WHERE, SUM, COUNT and GROUP-BY or equivalent queries on it?

Here is some sample data for what I am wanting to parse into a different, summarizing file. I look at the first field on each row and group or sum data from the rows starting with SD. I don't know how much I should go into the nitty-gritty, but as it were, I am not know enough PS yet to make my script sexy:

```
OH;1;ACME Inc;Arlington,VA 22204,USA;CSV;wiley@acme.inc;2018-01-07;;8074688;
SD;2;8074688;M/C;2018-01-05;00000523094871;04.01.18;04.01.18;2804,00;35,34;2768,66;6;89005257251;;;
SD;3;8074688;VISA;2018-01-05;00000523085587;05.01.18;05.01.18;1070,00;13,48;1056,52;1;91005299658;;;
SD;4;8074688;VISA;2018-01-05;00000523088281;05.01.18;05.01.18;3850,00;48,51;3801,49;4;91005299661;;;
SD;5;8074688;M/C;2018-01-05;00000523088281;05.01.18;05.01.18;1100,00;13,86;1086,14;2;91005299667;;;
SD;6;8074688;MSTO;2018-01-05;00000523088281;05.01.18;05.01.18;1100,00;13,86;1086,14;1;91005299671;;;
SD;7;8074688;MCDE;2018-01-05;00000523091962;04.01.18;04.01.18;46,00;0,58;45,42;1;91005299674;;;
SD;8;8074688;VISA;2018-01-05;00000524454189;02.01.18;04.01.18;900,00;11,32;888,68;19;91005299677;;;
SD;9;8074688;M/C;2018-01-05;00000524454189;02.01.18;04.01.18;420,00;5,29;414,71;9;91005299698;;;
SD;10;8074688;MSTO;2018-01-05;00000524454189;03.01.18;03.01.18;290,00;3,66;286,34;4;91005299709;;;
SD;11;8074688;VISA;2018-01-05;00000523082217;05.01.18;05.01.18;500,00;6,30;493,70;1;91005702322;;;
SD;12;8074688;M/C;2018-01-05;00000523082217;05.01.18;05.01.18;300,00;3,78;296,22;1;91005702325;;;
SD;13;8074688;VISA;2018-01-05;00000523087382;05.01.18;05.01.18;1116,00;14,06;1101,94;3;91005702328;;;
SD;14;8074688;M/C;2018-01-05;00000523087382;05.01.18;05.01.18;1840,00;23,19;1816,81;5;91005702333;;;
BD;15;8074688;;2018-01-07;0111800705600;15336,00;193,23;15142,77;57;;
TD;16;8074688;M/C;;00000523094 871;;;;89005257251; 
TD;17;8074688;MC CONS CR;2018-01-04;143954;;X9235;500,00;89005257251; 
TD;18;8074688;MC CONS CR;2018-01-04;150906;;X2107;52,00;89005257251; 
TD;19;8074688;MC CONS CR;2018-01-04;153840;;X6804;1000,00;89005257251; 
TD;20;8074688;MC CONS CR;2018-01-04;173636;;X2107;52,00;89005257251; 
TD;21;8074688;MC CONS CR;2018-01-04;193801;;X1042;200,00;89005257251; 
TD;22;8074688;MC CONS CR;2018-01-04;223605;;X3268;1000,00;89005257251;
```

Comment: You can use `[psobject]` or `[pscustomobject]` to create an object. Then built-in Cmldets such as `Where-Object`,`Group-Object` etc to get a subset of the object values. Is there something you can't do with that approach?

Comment: Those cmdlets work on arrays already. They will also work on the .Values or .Keys of a hash.

Comment: What is a specific example of how you would like to query an array right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample you have provided is a CSV with semi-colon delimiters.

A key concept to understand is that PowerShell deals with objects. Try this:

```
 $test = "some string"
 $test.Length          # returns 11
```

You didn't have to tell PowerShell the length of the string; it it a property of the string object.

Similarly:

```
$test2 = @("some string","some other string")
$test2.Count           # returns 2
```

Going back to your data, you can import it into PowerShell using [**`Import-Csv`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6):

```
$myData = Import-Csv -Path "c\path\to\your\file.txt" -Delimiter ";"
```

Bear in mind this will complain about lack of headers. Because your first row has less fields than most of the other rows, not because it recognises it's not a header; by default, `Import-Csv` will assume the first row is a header. You can specify headers using the `-Header` parameter, as documented in the above link.

The variable `$myData` is of type `PSCustomObject`. You could use [**`Get-Content`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) and manipulate the data into an array or hashtable... but why? `Import-Csv` gives you a nice object with the fields readily available as `NoteProperties`:

```
$myData.OH   # prints off the first column, assuming a header is not provided.
```

To manipulate the data in the same way I get the feeling you already do in SQL, you'll need to become familiar with what PowerShell has to offer. So here are some RTFM links to get you started ;-p

- [about_pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-6)
- [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6)
- [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-6)
- [Sort-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-6)
- [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6)
- [Measure-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-6)